# Azure subscription access between multiple subscription

Tags: azure, subscription, azure-virtual-network

I need help with some azure questions, sorry I new to azure

If under one agreement I have multiple subscriptions broken out into the following

production-client-a
production-client-b
IAT
UAT
Infrastructure

Can services in either "production-client-a" or "production-client-b" subscriptions access services in the "infrastructure-main", this would be like active directory / chef server / octopus deploy servers,etc

If this is possible, can you then control what networks have access to certain services in different subscriptions?
for example:

production-client-a subscription hosts (access to ports 80 + 443) to infrastructure-main subscription chef-server

How would you go about setting this up ?

Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe no, not directly. If these are PaaS services that can be used with some endpoints or connection strings, then yes. If you want to access resources from the subscription1 from subscription2 in like... one namespace or just select "subscription1 resource" from the subscription2 dashboard, then no.

If you want to put your Chef master in one subscription and add slaves from different subscriptions, there should not be a problem.

Comment: Would this be the answer in what i'm after ? or does this come with constraints ?       [link]https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-vnet-vnet-rm-ps/#difsub

Comment: Ugh. Changed the sentence about VNet. Yes, you may connect the different subscriptions and you will get the continuous IP space. For delegating the access using subnets - you may place the resources in the corresponding subnet. I am not sure if there is the such an access control like "that service is only for that subnet". You may take a look at RBAC model https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-built-in-roles/